# JSON_encode not outputting anything

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I want to send a query result from one php file to my javascript, I've used an `AJAX` which seems to work as it is getting data from my `BaseClass.php`. However when using `JSON_encode`, it is not outputting anything at all. So I can't work out how to send a query result from one php file(`MySQLDao.php`) to my `BaseClass.php` so I am then able to send it to my Javascript file.

My Code:

BaseClass.php:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require("Conn.php");
    require("MySQLDao.php");

    //$param=$_REQUEST['action'];

    //echo json_encode($_GET);


    //echo var_dump(json_encode($_GET));


    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $param = $_REQUEST['action'];
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $param .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);


    if (empty($param))
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved paige" .$param ."...";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $dao = new MySQLDao();
        if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
        {
            $returnValue["status"] = false;
            $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
            $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";
            ob_clean();
            echo json_encode($returnValue);
        }
        else
        {
            //Decodes data, dont change
            $body = json_decode($param, true);
            $recieved = $body["data"];

            //Gets the result of a query
            $result = $dao->getResults($recieved);


        }
        $dao->closeConnection();

        //Return the result of the query
        ob_clean();


        echo json_encode("param" .$param); 
        echo json_encode("body" .$body);
        echo json_encode("recieved" .$recieved);
        echo json_encode("result" .$result);

        exit();



    }
?>
```

output for the above echo statements:

```
"paramgetResults""body""recieved""result"
```

MySQLDao.php - this file holds the query result that I want to pass to my js

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //Class for holding queries
    class MySQLDao
    {

        var $dbhost = null;
        var $dbuser = null;
        var $dbpass = null;
        var $mysqli = null;
        var $dbname = null;
        var $result = null;


        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
            $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
            $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
        }

        //Attempt a connection to the database
        public function openConnection()
        {   

            //Try and connect to the database
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
            //If the connection threw an error, report it
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get method for retrieving the database conection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        //Close the connection to the database
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            //If there is a connection to the database then close it
            if ($this->mysqli != null)
                $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //-----------------------------------QUERY METHODS-------------------------------------

        public function getResults()
        {



            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description FROM room WHERE room.room_id = 1";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);


            //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //  $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');
            //  echo($obj);
            //  return $obj;
            //}

            echo json_encode($result);

            //echo($result);



            //return false;

        }


    }
?>
```

My AJAX code in my js file:

```
$.ajax ({

        type: "GET",
        datatype: "application/json",
        url: "BaseClass.php",
        data: { action : 'getResults' },
        //error: function(err){console.log(err)},
        success: function(output) {

            console.log(output);
            //alert(output);
        }
        //error, function(err){console.log(err)}
    });
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Check the console for errors. Another thing, your output is not valid json. You should put all the values into one array and encode that array. You should also have an `exit;` after your echo to stop the execution of the script and make sure that there's no other output.

Comment: echo "Your message : ", json_encode($yourArray), "\n";

Comment: `json_enocde()` first parameter should be `array` .

Comment: @JYoThI `json_encode` first parameter can be __anything__

Comment: @OP: I recommend to test the script by opening `/BaseClass.php?action=getResults` in a browser, without AJAX for now. Also, why not use `$_GET`? Why open the input stream just to read GET params...? Finally, you need to echo *one* `json_encode`, which should have a single array/object as parameter.

Comment: Shall I create the array in the getResults() function in my MySQLDao.php and then Json_encode?

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice, but your method `getResults()` doesn't actually _return_ anything. You're just trying to json_encode the mysqli response object (which is what Mysqli::query() returns). There's too many issues here. You need to read up in the methods and functions you're using, learn about them and try them out on their own before combining them to one script.

Comment: Try debugging by methods [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-message.php)